# Keyword OPTIONAL in TYPE in Fortran does not work

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran2003

I try the following codes, and find the OPTIONAL keyword does not work. The compile is ok, but the runtime error will prompt.

I know usually the INTERFACE should be used in the module to provide enough information for the routines. I also try that, but failed to finish the compile no matter where I put the INTERFACE.

I have read some codes which use OPTIONAL in the TYPE declaration. https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n1a3.htm

Now I am using intel visual fortran, so is there any difference?

```
module testA_m
implicit none

type :: onion_c
    contains
    procedure :: testA
end type

contains

subroutine testA(this, a,b)
    implicit none
    class(onion_c) :: this
    real*8 :: a
    real*8, optional :: b

    write(*,*) a,b
end subroutine    
end module

program main
call testIt()
end program

subroutine testIt()
use testA_m
implicit none
type(onion_c) :: onion
real*8 :: c1 
real*8 :: c2

c1 = 1.0d0
c2 = 2.0d0
call onion.testA(c1)

end subroutine
```

Comment: The error message is ''access violation"

Comment: The Portland Group article referenced in the question above does *not* include `type` declarations with `optional` components, only `subroutines` with `optional` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are trying to print `b`, which is not passed to the subroutine. Hence the access violation.

You should check for `b` first:

```
subroutine testA(this, a,b)
    implicit none
    class(onion_c) :: this
    real*8 :: a
    real*8, optional :: b

    if ( present(b) ) then
      write(*,*) a,b
    else
      write(*,*) a
    endif
end subroutine
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but what I really want to do is set a default value for b. Suppose b is not present, I want b takes the default value. If b is passed, there the passed value will be taken.

Comment: real*8, optional :: b = 3.0d0   maybe is the best solution for me. Unfortunately it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I need another variable for the real operation. Like the following.

I am still looking forward the better solution to use `b` directly.

```
subroutine testA(this, a,b)
    implicit none
    class(onion_c)   :: this
    real*8           :: a
    real*8, optional :: b
    real*8           :: bUsed

    if ( present(b) ) then
        bUsed = b
        write(*,*) a,bUsed
    else
        bUsed = 2.00d0
        write(*,*) a,bUsed
    endif
end subroutine
```

Comment: Or, more simply, `bUsed = 2.0d0; if (present(b)) bUsed = b`

Answer (score 0):

Because Fortran does not support a program like

```
subroutine testA( this, a, b=10.0d0 )
```

I usually define a macro like the following in a common header file

```
#define _optval_(x,xopt,default)   x = default; if (present(xopt)) x = xopt
```

and then use it at the top of a subroutine like

```
subroutine testA(this, a,b_)
class(onion_c)   :: this
real*8           :: a
real*8, optional :: b_
real*8  b

_optval_( b, b_, 10.0d0 )  !! use only b from here on
```

Although this is not essentially different from writing several IF constructs, I feel it is a bit more convenient (at least for simple variables) because no need to worry about whether b is optional or not in the subsequent code. (But frankly, I hope Fortran2020 or so will support a syntax like the first example...)